# Co-ordinates of the four points of a uiview which has been rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, xcode4

Is it possible to get this? If so, can anyone please tell me how?

Comment: You could use some basic trig (sin and cosine, arcsin and arccos) to figure out the coordinates of all corners of a rectangle that has been rotated.

Comment: But currently I only have the origin.x and origin.y values. With only this how can I calculate the other coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint topLeft = view.bounds.origin;
topLeft = [[view superview] convertPoint:topLeft fromView:view];

CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(view.bounds.origin.x + view.bounds.width, view.bounds.origin.y);
topRight = [[view superview] convertPoint:topRight fromView:view];

// ... likewise for the other points
```

The first point is in the view's coordinate space, which is always "upright". Then the next statement finds the point that point corresponds to in the parent view's coordinate space. Note for an un-transformed view, that would be equal to `view.frame.origin`. The above calculations give the equivalent of the corners of `view.frame` for a transformed view.

Comment: This works, although I'm not sure how to use this to get the bottom left coordinate. Also, if an image is involved it is more accurate to use `view.image.size.width` rather then `view.bounds.width`.

Comment: Just figured out bottom left coordinate: `CGPoint bottomRight = CGPointMake(self.dragView.bounds.origin.x + self.dragView.image.size.width, self.dragView.bounds.origin.y + self.dragView.image.size.height);
    bottomRight = [[self.dragView superview] convertPoint:bottomRight fromView:self.dragView];`

Answer (score 3):

- Get the four points of the frame of your view (`view.frame`)
- Retrieve the `CGAffineTransform` applied to your view (`view.transform`)
- Then apply this same affine transform to the four points using `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` (and sibling methods of the [CGAffineTransform Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html))

Comment: Note that I haven't tested it, but you may need to apply a translation to make the origin of the transform (which is the anchorPoint of your view, probably its center by default if you didn't change it) point at 0,0, then apply the transform itself, and do the translation back again. Probably try both cases to be sure. Don't forget to manage the coordinate system you are using (i.e. which is the reference / origin point / coordinate space in which your CGPoint coordinates are expressed (probably the superview's bounds coordinate system but centered at the anchorPoint of the subview)